# Wordpress Set featured Image from frontend

Tags: wordpress, image-processing, wordpress-featured-image

I updated wordpress to version 3.5 and one of my functions not working anymore.

I have a page with post form from frontend where users can submit posts to one category.

After the upgrade to 3.5, I can create post fine and upload image too in the media library but, the function that I use to attach the uploaded image like featured image to the post not working for some reason that I can't find.

I use this code to set featured image after the post is sucessful created and the image is uploaded to the media library. I can capture the `$post_id` and the `$attach_id
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );`

I made change to the code too but without luck

`add_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id,true );`

I manually add `post_meta` to the post in the database the image is appearing as featured fine but I must set the `_edit_lock` first.

When I add this code the `_edit_lock` is inserted in the `post_meta` but not the `_thumbnail_id`

```
add_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id,true );
add_post_meta( $post_id, '_edit_lock', time().':1',true);
```

In WordPress 3.5 is any restrictions about `_thumbnail_id post_meta` execution from fronted ?

Comment: try set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbnail_id );

Comment: that was the built in function that plugin use to set the featured image and did not work. I found temporary solution  to set the post to draft and not to pending after that the featured image is set